# Wrapping a function's arguments by another function and calling it with some timeout period

Tags: javascript

```
function getProxy(fn, ms, a, b)
{
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    this.ms=ms;    
    this.fn=fn;
    fn();
}

function fn(a, b)
{
    return a+b;
}   
var ms=setTimeout(fn, 1000);
```

Above there is a function name getProxy which is used to wrap the values of it's arguments in such a way that whenever the function fn is called it should return the values of a and b with certain timeout period.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Whatever the code I have written is not working. So I want to know my mistake.

Comment: A) You are not passing arguments to `fn`. (B) Variable `ms` get the timer identifier, not the returned value from `fn` because `fn` will be executed in future.

Comment: Still it's showing undefined values.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be in `getProxy()`? `this` should be used in methods of an object, not top-level functions.

Comment: You never call `getProxy`. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Can you suggest some other solution for it with the help of which I can wrap the arguments passed to getProxy method.

Comment: Use a closure or `fn.bind()`.

Comment: how should I use a closure in this

Comment: How do I call getProxy method so that the correct values goes into it's parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169307/discussion-between-newbie-and-barmar).

Comment: You need a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getProxy() {
    //arguments;
    var context = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var fn = args[0], ms = args[1];
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(args, context);
        console.log(fn.apply(context, args.slice(2)));
    }, ms);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> whenever the function `fn` is called it should return the values of a and b with certain timeout period.

From the statement above I understand you need to call `fn` at some moment in the future and get the value it returns.

If you don't care about the value returned by `fn()` then you don't even need the `getProxy()` function. All you have to do is to call:

```
setTimeout(fn, ms, a, b)
```

This call will postpone the execution of `fn(a, b)` with `ms` milliseconds. `fn(a, b)` will be executed asynchronously but the value it returns is lost.

You need to use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) to asynchronously run a function and capture the value it returns.

This is how your code should look like:

```js
    function getProxy(fn, ms, a, b) {
        // Create and return a new Promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // Start the async operation
            setTimeout(function() {
                // After the timeout, call fn(a, b) and resolve (fulfill)
                // the promise with the value returned by it
                resolve(fn(a, b));
            }, ms);
        });
    }

    // The promised computation
    function fn(a, b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }

    // Start processing
    let x = 2, y = 3;
    console.log(`Delaying the computation of ${x}+${y}...`)

    // Create the promise; it will run asynchronously
    let proxy = getProxy(fn, 1000, x, y);
    // Set event handlers for its completion
    proxy.then(function(result) {
        // ... 1000 ms later
        console.log(`Computation completed successfully: ${x}+${y}=${result}`);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // handle the rejected promise (it won't be rejected in this example)
        console.log(`Computation failed. Reason: ${error}`);
    });
```

Read about [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thanks for the solution...can't we capture the values without promise and by using bind

Comment: When a function is executed asynchronously, it returns after the code that started it completes. There is no direct way to return a value to the code that invoked it because that code completed its job and is not running any more. The function can put the value it computes (`a+b`) into a global variable (not recommended) or it can pass it to a callback function to do something with it.

Comment: A `Promise` is not very different than a callback function but has some advantages and one of them is that the code is easier to read and understand. The callback is passed to `.then()` and executed after the promise is fullfilled (when the timeout passes and `f(a, b)` is executed). Behind the scene, the `getProxy()` function together with the `.then()` and `.catch()` calls create a chain of functions that executes asynchronously to do a job. The code that calls `getProxy()` then continues its processing independent of what the chain does and completes before the chain completes its execution.

Comment: [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does not help with asynchronous processing (`setTimeout()` works asynchronously). What is does is to tell a function to use a certain object as `this` when it runs (it creates a new function that has `this` linked to the passed object).

Comment: @barmar typo, indeed. Thank you for fixing it.